# Why a bubble is needed?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu, pipeline

Consider the following MIPS instructions:

`lw $5, 8($5)`
`sw $5, 12($6)`

Now, as far as I understand, `Memory[8 + $5]` is available to us at the begining of stage #5, whereas `sw` needs `$5` information at stage #4 so we can just forward. Why do we also need a bubble/stall?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you either forward *or* place a bubble, unless you do not have the datum required to forward in which case you may need to stall anyways.
In your example, suppose your pipeline allows forwarding from MEM stage to EX stage. 
You can do a time diagram showing in which stage is each instruction.

Without forwarding:

```
time              1  2  3   4  5   6   7  8
lw $5, 8($5)      IF ID EX MEM WB
sw $5, 12($6)        IF ID-------> EX MEM WB
```

you have to stall two cycles for `$5` to become available to the `EX` stage of the second instruction.

With forwarding:

```
time              1  2  3   4  5   6  7  
lw $5, 8($5)      IF ID EX MEM WB
sw $5, 12($6)        IF ID---> EX MEM WB
```

In this case the data read from memory is available to be forwarded the `EX` stage of `sw` instruction.

Comment: I've seen a solution suggesting you need both stall and forwarding. I guess it's false..

Comment: You can write a simple time diagram showing in which step is each instruction at any point in time, then check if the forwarding allows you to use that input as required data for the desired stage. If it can, then you don't need a bubble.

Comment: @RonErikson: In this case, assuming you forward to EX stage you'd need to stall one cycle

Comment: gusbro, your second diagram suggests there's a bubble (the arrow) also with forwarding. I am confused.

Comment: @RonErikson: yes, I am saying that in this case with forwarding (from MEM to EX) there is a 1 cycle bubble, and without forwarding there would be a two-cycle bubble.

Comment: but why do we need a bubble? The value of $5 is availbable to us at stage #5 of the first instruction. The second instruction needs it at stage #4 so we can **just** forward without bubble. isn't it right?

Comment: @RonErikson: Well, you have to look at the block diagram of your architecture, but usually the $5 should be available atmost at the end of the ID stage of the pipeline. Just check your MIPS diagram.

Comment: Doesn't a typical `sw` use the `EX` stage to compute the destination address, requiring the value to store only at the beginning of the `MEM` stage? That would mean there's no stall needed with forwarding, right?

Comment: @DanielJour: I guess you have to look at the block diagram to tell. If there is a forward unit from MEM stage (output, after read) to MEM stage (input, before write) then you would not need a bubble. If there is no such forward unit then you have to stall.